# Completion Block Error Generated when accessing User account in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, completionhandler

I am attempting to create a completion block while pulling a users profile from a firebase table.  I need it to complete before I allow it to pass back a value.

Here is what I have so far:

```
func getProf(email: String, pass: String, completionBlock: @escaping (_ success: Bool) -> (Int)) {
        let ref = Database.database().reference()
        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        ref.child("users").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            self.zDaily = value?["qday"] as? Int ?? 0
        }) {
            if let error = error {
                completionBlock(false)
            } else {
                completionBlock(true)
                return zDaily
            }
        }
        
    }
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Cannot convert value of type '() -> _' to expected argument type '((Error) -> Void)?'
```

I'm not sure how to fix this, any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if that'll fix the error. If it doesn't, then I think I know the issue and it would be with your error block and your observeEvent.

Edit: Just made a change to return an error object from the observeEvent.

```
 func getProf(email: String, pass: String, completionBlock: @escaping (Bool, Int) -> ()) {
            let ref = Database.database().reference()
            let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
            ref.child("users").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                self.zDaily = value?["qday"] as? Int ?? 0
            }) { (error) in //Added return error value - this may fix your error
                if let error = error {
                    completionBlock(false, 0) //Add default 0 to return if error
                } else {
                    completionBlock(true, zDaily) //Added zDaily as Int to return
                    //return zDaily - return will not return in async function so you can return the value in completionBlock above.
                }
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: It is throwing the Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Error' error.  It doesn't like the optional chaining for the error.  Still trying to figure out how to fix that.

Comment: Hmm, never got the notification - were you able to solve the error?